# What to reference in the shebang python26 or python2.6

Tags: python, shebang

For a Python script I need a specific Python version. Now my installation of Python 2.6 contains both python26 and python2.6

Which one should I put in the shebang?

Option 1:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.6
```

Option 2:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python26
```

**EDIT**: Yes, there is a reason not to use plain python. In some of our environments in the university python is linked to python2.4 and my code uses quite some 2.6 features.

Comment: What's `Python 26`? If you are referring to the Windows installation, you don't need the `shebang` (#!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just checked on my Linux system there is only `python2.6` not `python26` so the former looks better.

Just to clarify, I would use conditional imports instead, in my case I need `OrderedDict` which is python 2.7+ only;

```
try:
    from collections import OrderedDict
except ImportError:
    print("Python 2.7+ is needed for this script.")
    sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, I checked after this answer an Ubuntu machine and it wasn't there. On our CentOS and Fedora boxes both are always there!

Comment: I think you'll find that it depends on which Ubuntu release you're using.  I'm using Maverick, and python2.6 is there.  The upcoming Natty release might not have it by default, but has it available if you want to install it.  For reference:  http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python

Comment: I would use conditional imports instead, bail out if the needed functionality is not there.

Answer (score 8):

You can't always guarantee that the shebang will be used (or even that the user will have that version).

You shouldn't really limit to a specific version exactly. It's best to require *at least* a given version (if your code works on Python 2.6, why wouldn't it work on Python 2.7? I might not have Python 2.6 installed in a few months time.)

I would stick with the `/usr/bin/env python` shebang and instead dynamically detect the version. Believe it or not, the "normal" way of doing this is:

```
import sys
ver = sys.version[:3]
```

That will give you a 3-character string such as "2.6" or "2.7". I would just check that the first character = '2' (assuming you want to prevent Python 3 from running your scripts, since it's largely incompatible) and the third character >= '6'.

**Edit**: See Petr's comment -- use `sys.version_info[0:2]` instead (gives you a pair like `(2, 6)` or `(2, 7)`.

Comment: Instead of sys.version (which is a string), you should use sys.version_info which is a tuple like (2, 6, 6, 'final', 0). Check the sys.version documentation saying “Do not extract version information out of it”: http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.version

Comment: I stand corrected. I must have originally been reading ancient advice (obviously, version_info was added in version 2.0, so at one point in the past, people must have gotten the version out of the string).

Comment: mguica and Petr, thanks for the help with this.  That's just what I needed.

Comment: Comparing tuples is a bit boring, lets use hexversion instead: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.hexversion -- if (0x02070000 <= sys.hexversion < 0x03000000) :)

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you just use `/usr/bin/python` instead? Is there any reason for not doing that?

If you don't have it already, you can create a link to it using this command:

`ln -s /usr/bin/python26 /usr/bin/python`

This ensures compatibility if you ever upgrade your python in the future.

Comment: I agree, but not that it's better to use `/usr/bin/env python` rather than `/usr/bin/python`. The former will search for a program called `python` in the user's search path, while the latter requires that it's in `/usr/bin`, which may or may not be true depending on the distro and the setup. (For example, on most distros if Python was installed manually it will be in `/usr/local/bin`.)

Comment: No I mean instead of using `/usr/bin/python26`

Comment: Well yeah, I agree that you should use `python` instead of `python2.6`. But in addition, you should use `/usr/bin/env whatever` instead of `/usr/bin/whatever`.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question now, in some systems here env python links to python2.4, which is not sufficient

Comment: You can still use `/usr/bin/env python2.6`. The `/usr/bin/env x` call will look up program `x`, as though run from the command line, and feed the following script into it's `stdin`. If you have python 2.6 available at `/usr/bin/python2.6`, then `/usr/bin/env python2.6` will find it. Same if you have it at `/usr/local/bin/python2.6` etc. The use of `/usr/bin/env` removes the need to do any funny linking or other trickery to get around different paths, and should pretty much always be used.